# При вводе данных в MySQL в Intellij IDEA корректно отображается только латиница

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlet, jdbc

```
public class reg extends HttpServlet {
static String name;
static String password;
static String age;
static String login;
Connection connection;
PreparedStatement pst;
static String pass = "1234";
static String root = "root";
static String connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    name=req.getParameter("name");
    password=req.getParameter("password");
    age=req.getParameter("age");
    login=req.getParameter("login");
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(age);
    System.out.println(login);
    System.out.println(password);
    try{
       //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        connection= DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, root,pass);
        pst=connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (NAME, AGE, LOGIN, PASSWORD) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1, name);
        pst.setString(2,age);
        pst.setString(3,login);
        pst.setString(4,password);
        pst.execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();System.out.println("Ooops!");}
}
```

}

С веб-страницы отправляю данные (имя, возраст, логин, пароль) все заносится в таблицу, но то что написано буквами русского алфавита отображается некорректно, ниже пример вывода в консоль и таблицы. В настройках проекта выставил utf-8 - не помогает :(
[image: Консоль]
[image: Таблица]

Comment: проверьте на каком этапе ломается кодировка. Я почти уверен, что с клиента вам приходит уже поломанная.

Comment: При использовании сервлетов рекомендуют применять фильтры. [вот тут пример](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/encodings_webapp.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в сервере Tomcat, он по умолчанию использует  ISO-8859-1. Можно использовать языковой фильтр, а можно вручную конвертировать в другую кодировку как `new String(req.getParameter("AdText").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));` Источник: [См. комментарии](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/accept-charset)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать следующее в метод doGet перед своим кодом

```
req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Что бы данные от сервера в браузер передавались также в нормальном виде нужно дописать ещё

```
resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло :(